# The node to be inserted is from a different document context even after using import

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I am trying to move node from one xml document to another xml document but am getting an exception. Below is my code:

```
XmlDocument xdocedgeonly = new XmlDocument();

using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(data))
using (MemoryStream output = new MemoryStream())
{
    xdocedgeonly.Load(ms);
}

XmlElement alldocsnode = xdocedgeonly.SelectSingleNode("//Doc") as XmlElement;
alldocsnode.ParentNode.RemoveAll(); 

using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(data))
using (MemoryStream output = new MemoryStream())
{
    XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
    xdoc.Load(ms);

    XmlNodeList docsnode = xdoc.SelectNodes("//Doc");
    foreach (XmlElement docattribute in docsnode)
    {                        
        XmlElement edgeDocsNode  = xdocedgeonly.SelectSingleNode("//Docs") as XmlElement;
        XmlNode importedNode = xdoc.ImportNode(docattribute, true);
        edgeDocsNode.AppendChild(importedNode);
    }
}
```

Here's my exception message:

> 'The node to be inserted is from a different document context'

Comment: Could you post what attempts you made to resolve this error?

Comment: Initial I was tried with "edgeDocsNode.AppendChild(docattribute)" but it was failed.after that I found somewhere on the internet that first, I need to import that node then I can append it into new XML.

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question and share some XML that we can use to reproduce the problem, and some indication as to what the result should be -- i.e. a [mcve]?  It looks like you are using the same XML for both documents by the way, as `data` is loaded into both `xdocedgeonly` and `xdoc`.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable response, the issue  is fixed now.